# Building a dependency tree of file used in a batch job using Python

Tags: python, text, tree

I am trying to build a tree like dependency for the files used in a batch job.The input to the program will be a .CSV file which has 4 columns and is of the following format.
`Jobname,StepNumber,Program,FileName,Mode`
A sample data will look like as below:

```
J1  S1  PGM1    F1  Input
J1  S1  PGM1    F2  Input 
J1  S1  PGM1    F3  Output
J1  S1  PGM1    F4  Output
J1  S2  PGM2    F3  Input
J1  S2  PGM2    F6  Output
J1  S3  PGM3    F6  Input
J1  S3  PGM3    F7  Input
J1  S3  PGM3    F8  Output
J1  S4  PGM4    F8  Input
J1  S4  PGM4    F2  Input
J1  S4  PGM4    F10 Output
J1  S4  PGM4    F11 Output
```

Trying to build a dependency of files used in the job like below:

```
J1:F1,F2-->F3-->F6,F7-->F8,F2-->F10,F11
J1:F1,F2-->F4
```

Main objective of building a tree like structure is because it will be used as an input for searching the file.In this if we need to list the files that are input to `F6`, then `F1,F2,F3` will be easily identified using a tree like structure.Is there a better way to  search a file rather than constructing a dependency tree?

Added to the above,I am using Python, but i am not familiar with any library for constructing a tree like structure?

Comment: [Airflow](http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/index.html) is a Python project that allows you to "author workflows as directed acyclic graphs"

Comment: Is there an alternative to this?